# How to do transaction operation for a number of mysql queries in node js using promise?

Tags: mysql, node.js, bluebird

I have 27 mysql update queries on a single table. All these queries are to be run in a transaction mode, like if one operation fails all other updated queries should rollback.

How I will implement this nodejs with promises?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you use mysql driver found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql).

According to [documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#transactions), this drivers natively supports transactions like this (copied from documentation):

```
connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET title=?', title, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
      return connection.rollback(function() {
        throw error;
      });
    }

    connection.query('INSERT INTO log SET data=?', log, function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        return connection.rollback(function() {
          throw error;
        });
      }
      connection.commit(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return connection.rollback(function() {
            throw err;
          });
        }
        console.log('success!');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Since you mentioned promises, you would want to use [promise-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) package which wraps mysql calls in Bluebird promises.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach to handle your secnario.

- Create an array of queries which needs to be run. In below example I have created queries and their placeholder values and passed them as an array of objects
- return a promise to caller which gets resolved when all queries supposed to be run inside a transaction finished
- start the transaction
- run queries one by one inside transaction block
- store the result inside an accumulator as soon as query returns result
- if all transactions are complete the commit the transaction and return accumulated result to caller
- otherwise rollback the transaction and return the error to caller via promise

Below is the approach which I have mentioned -

```js
function executeTransaction(queries) {
    try {
      const connection = yield getConnectionObj({/* your db params to get connection */)
  
      let results = []

      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connection.beginTransaction(function (err) {
          if (err) throw err

          console.log("Starting transaction")

          queries
            .reduce(function (sequence, queryToRun) {
              return sequence.then(function () {
                parent.query(queryToRun.query, queryToRun.values)
                /* pass your query and connection to a helper function and execute query there */
                return queryConnection(
                  connection,
                  query,
                  queryParams,
                ).then(function (res) {
                  /* Accumulate resposes of all queries */
                  results = results.concat(res)
                })
              }).catch(function (error) {
                reject(error)
              })
            }, Promise.resolve())
            .then(function () {
              connection.commit(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                 /* rollback in case of any error */
                  connection.rollback(function () {
                    throw err
                  })
                }
                console.log('Transactions were completed!')
                /* release connection */
                connection.release()
                /* resolve promise with all results */
                resolve({ results })
              })
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              console.log('Transaction failed!')
              connection.rollback(function () {
                console.log('Abort Transaction !!!')
                throw err
              })
            })
        })
      })
   /* End Transaction */

    } catch (error) {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Lakshmipriya I hope it helps.